# R Time Series ARIMA function returns 0 (non-NA) cases

Tags: r, time-series, azure-machine-learning-service, arima

I'm new to R. I'm using Azure Machine Learning Studio to try and predict when a coupon or offer (marketing promotion) might be redeemed based on historical redemptions. Here is my data.

[image]

**Here is my R script.**

```
#ARIMA Seasonal / ARIMA non-seasonal 
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)
# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables

dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame
dataset2 <- maml.mapInputPort(2) # class: data.frame

######dataset1$RedeemedOn <- as.POSIXlt(dataset1$RedeemedOn, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
######dataset2$RedeemedOn <- as.POSIXlt(dataset2$RedeemedOn, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

dataset1$RedeemedOn <- as.Date(dataset1$RedeemedOn,  # Character vector to convert
             format= "%y/%m/%d")   

dataset2$RedeemedOn <- as.Date(dataset2$RedeemedOn,  # Character vector to convert
             format= "%y/%m/%d")   

#Enter the seasonality of the timeseries here
#For non-seasonal model use '1' as the seasonality
seasonality<-12
labels <- as.numeric(dataset1$OfferId)
timeseries <- ts(labels,frequency=seasonality)
model <- auto.arima(timeseries)
numPeriodsToForecast <- ceiling(max(dataset2$RedeemedOn)) - ceiling(max(dataset1$RedeemedOn))
#numPeriodsToForecast <- ceiling(max(dataset2$hour)) - ceiling(max(dataset1$hour))
numPeriodsToForecast <- max(numPeriodsToForecast, 0)
forecastedData <- forecast(model, h=numPeriodsToForecast)
forecastedData <- as.numeric(forecastedData$mean)

output <- data.frame(RedeemedOn=dataset2$RedeemedOn,forecast=forecastedData)
data.set <- output

# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port
maml.mapOutputPort("data.set");
```

**Here is the error.**

Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
0 (non-NA) cases

Am I even doing this correctly? Will this predict future offer/coupon redemptions based on previous RedeemedOn dates and times?

**EDIT 1**

```
#ARIMA Seasonal / ARIMA non-seasonal 
install.packages("forecast")
library(forecast)
# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables

dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame
dataset2 <- maml.mapInputPort(2) # class: data.frame

dataset1$RedeemedOn <- as.POSIXct(dataset1$RedeemedOn, format="%d/%m/%Y")
dataset2$RedeemedOn <- as.POSIXct(dataset2$RedeemedOn, format="%d/%m/%Y")
#dataset1$RedeemedOn <- as.POSIXct(dataset1$RedeemedOn, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
#dataset2$RedeemedOn <- as.POSIXct(dataset2$RedeemedOn, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")



#####dataset1$RedeemedOn <- as.Date(dataset1$RedeemedOn,  # Character vector to convert
             #####format= "%y/%m/%d")   

#####dataset2$RedeemedOn <- as.Date(dataset2$RedeemedOn,  # Character vector to convert
             #####format= "%y/%m/%d")   

#Enter the seasonality of the timeseries here
#For non-seasonal model use '1' as the seasonality
seasonality<-12
labels <- as.numeric(dataset1$OfferId)
timeseries <- ts(labels,frequency=seasonality)
model <- auto.arima(timeseries)
numPeriodsToForecast <- ceiling(max(dataset2$RedeemedOn)) - ceiling(max(dataset1$RedeemedOn))
#numPeriodsToForecast <- ceiling(max(dataset2$hour)) - ceiling(max(dataset1$hour))
numPeriodsToForecast <- max(numPeriodsToForecast, 0)
forecastedData <- forecast(model, h=numPeriodsToForecast)
forecastedData <- as.numeric(forecastedData$mean)

#output <- data.frame(RedeemedOn=dataset2$RedeemedOn,forecast=forecastedData)
output <- data.frame(date=format(dataset2$RedeemedOn, "%d/%m/%y"),forecast=forecastedData)
data.set <- output

# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port
maml.mapOutputPort("data.set");
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You are using the wrong format strings (hence the NA values). You need to take several staps backward and actually learn R before attempting this. Time-series analysis seems less suited to this than would event/survival analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @42-! I've read up on R and watched a lot of videos, but I'm new to this and it appears to have a steep learning curve. I will look into event/survival analysis. Since I'm learning, what would the correct format for the date be on this? I've tried a POSIXlt format and I tried adding the hour, minute and second to the as.Date method.

Comment: Generally POSIXct is preferred to POSIXlt, since the latter does not play well with dataframes or matrices. I don't think the + operator will "add" hours or minutes to Date-classed objects.

Comment: @42- Even though this won't give me a good result, I'm just trying to get this to work. I'm using POSIXct now and I changed my output line. Please see edit 1 above. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what this code might do. The data is not available and I cannot tell if you are getting error or garbage results or wonderful predictions.